# An induction proof on a version of "prime avoidance" from Atiyah-McDonald.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The proposition is 1.11 from the commutative algebra book.

*Let $\mathfrak{p}_1, \dots, \mathfrak{p}_n$ be prime ideals and let $\mathfrak{a}$ be an ideal contained in the union of those prime ideals.  Then $\mathfrak{a} \subset \mathfrak{p}_i$ for some $i$.*

> This is proved by induction on $n$ of the form $\mathfrak{a} \not\subset \mathfrak{p}_i (i =1\dots n) \implies \mathfrak{a} \not\subset \bigcup \mathfrak{p}_i$.  It is certainly true for $n = 1$.  If $n \gt 1$ and the result is true for $n-1$, then for each $i$ there's $x_i \in \mathfrak{a}$ such that $x_i \notin \mathfrak{p}_j$ whenever $i \neq j$.   [...]

I don't see the logic in this.  Let $x_i \in \mathfrak{a}$ such that $x_i \notin \mathfrak{p}_i$, for all $i \neq j$, but what if $\mathfrak{p}_i \subset \mathfrak{p}_j$ for some $j$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the induction hypothesis. The case $\mathfrak p_i\subset\mathfrak p_j$ poses no problems since there is no claim that $x_i$ belongs to $\mathfrak p_i$.

Comment: So for general case $n$, if $\mathfrak{a} \not\subset \mathfrak{p}_i, i= 1\dots n$, then for any $n-1$ of the ideals there's $x_i$ not in any of the ideals, by induction hypothesis.  Makes sense now.  Thanks!